# Allocate object memory statically; intialize it dynamically?

Tags: programming, c++

I have an object whose constructor gets passed a parameter. If I know the parameter value at compile time, I can construct the object statically:

`static FOOOBJ foo(3);`

(I understand that it isn't really done statically, i.e. by the compiler, but is actually done during setup).

But if I don't know the parameter value at compile time, I'd still like to pre-allocate space for the object but construct the object in that space at run time. Can it be done without a separate `.initialize()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an `initialize()` method to a class is contrary to the principle of a class constructor, i.e. once a class instance has been **constructed**, it should be "**ready to use**".

As suggested by Ignacio's answer, C++ placement syntax is much better for your purpose.

However, with Arduino libraries, placement syntax is not supported "out of the box", so you  have to implement it yourself; don't fear, that is quite straightforward:

```
void* operator new(size_t size, void* ptr)
{
    return ptr;
}
```

Placement syntax can be a complex beast in C++, but for your specific purpose, its usage can be rather simple:

```
static char buffer[sizeof FOOOBJ];
static FOOOBJ* foo;

void setup() {
    ...
    foo = new (buffer) FOOOBJ(3);
    ...
}
```

The difference with your current code is that `foo` is now a pointer, hence any method call will use `->` instead of `.`.

If you absolutely want to keep using `foo` as an instance and not a pointer, then you can do it (but I don't advise it as explained later) by using a **reference** instead:

```
static char buffer[sizeof FOOOBJ];
static FOOOBJ& foo = *((FOOOBJ*) buffer);

void setup() {
    ...
    new (buffer) FOOOBJ(3);
    ...
}
```

The problem with this code, is that you cannot know if `foo` has already been constructed with a real `FOOOBJ` instance or not; using a pointer, you can always check if it is `0` or not.

Using placement syntax, you must be aware that you cannot `delete` the `foo` instance above. If you want to destroy `foo` (i.e. ensure that its destructor is called), then you have to explicitly call the destructor:

```
foo->~FOOOBJ();
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the syntax but that makes total sense! Does the constructor need to be aware of / designed for it? `FOOOBJ` is a OneWire object, using Jim Studt's library (v2.2). I'm getting the message `error: no matching function for call to 'operator new(unsigned int, byte [14])'` on the `new` call. It looks like avr-g++ may not understand the syntax.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I'm using Eclipse for my Arduino projects and what I checked it, it seemed to work, except that what worked was Eclipse C++ compilation, not avr-g++! I have edited my answer to show a simple workaround.

Comment: Regarding your question on constructor, ther is no specific requirement, but if the constructor itself performs dynamic allocation, then placement new will not prevent it.

Comment: I'm also using Eclipse - what C++ compiler is yours configured with? Plus looking at the OneWire constructor, it doesn't `new` anything, it just initializes some i/o.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse with http://eclipse.baeyens.it/ plugin (which uses Arduino IDE tools, ie avr-g++ + Arduino libs); but the C++ compilation occurs on-the-fly with Eclipse C++, and uses avr-g++ only when launching the Arduino build. I had not checked the latter step initially.

Comment: This is clearly the right approach. That  my current tools don't support it directly is unfortunate but it points me in the direction I need to go. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [placement syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) to specify an existing allocation in which to instantiate the class.

```
FOOOBJ foo(0);

 ...

  FOOOBJ *f = new (foo) FOOOBJ(3);
```

Comment: I'd suggest to replace the declaration of `foo` with `char foo[sizeof FOOOBJ];` so that `FOOOBJ` constructor does not get called for `foo` which could be a real problem depending on what the constructor does.